# How to insert product details in drupal_commerce product table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I have created a E-commerce site by using Drupal commerce which is a clone of a shopping site created by Ektron. Now my client requirement is that if he insert a product in that site(which is created in Ektron)  it will also incorporated in my site when we run import.

So I need to know how drupal_commerce insert their product details in the table.Any help regarding this wold be appreciable . If anyone need any further clarification please let me know .

Also I have some entity fields as well . Like author name , least price etc how to insert those values as well

Thanks in advance

Comment: those who downgrade my question please dare to answer it .. let know your idea as well :)

Comment: Those who downgrade your ques are really dum-ass. Otherwise they would  at-least leave a comment .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one ..

```
$values = array (
                'price' => 9271.00 ,
                'currency_code' => 'USD' ,
        );

                $cp = commerce_product_new('product');
                $cp->is_new = TRUE;
                $cp->revision_id = NULL;
                $cp->uid = 1;
                $cp->status = 1;
                $cp->created = $cp->changed = time();
                $cp->sku = '#12sku';
                $cp->title = 'New Title';
                $cp->language = 'und';

                $cp->commerce_price = array ( LANGUAGE_NONE => array ( 0 => array (
                    'amount' => $values[ 'price' ] ,
                    'currency_code' => $values[ 'currency_code' ],
                    ) ) );
                $cp->field_list_price = array ( LANGUAGE_NONE => array ( 0 => array (
                        'amount' => '300.00' ,
                        'currency_code' => $values[ 'currency_code' ],
                ) ) );

                $cp->field_isbn = array ( LANGUAGE_NONE => array ( 0 => array (
                        'value' => '#isbnn' ,
                        ) ) );
```